# Is it possible to left-align the row label in a Row Facet?

Tags: vega-lite

Is it possible to left-align the row label in a Row Facet?

In this case the row field of "Sub-Category".

For example, ...

Accessories

Appliances

Art

....................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
  {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-01-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 2126,
        "Profit": 476
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-02-29T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 2437,
        "Profit": 623
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-03-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 3952,
        "Profit": 1192
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-04-30T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 2142,
        "Profit": 358
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-05-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 3751,
        "Profit": 1190
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-06-30T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 4849,
        "Profit": 1028
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-07-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 7589,
        "Profit": 2403
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-08-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 4962,
        "Profit": 1154
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-09-30T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 9727,
        "Profit": 2778
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-10-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 5032,
        "Profit": 909
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-11-30T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 8390,
        "Profit": 2181
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-12-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 4989,
        "Profit": 1380
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-01-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 2548,
        "Profit": 423
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-02-29T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 3521,
        "Profit": 977
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-03-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 2474,
        "Profit": 308
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-04-30T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 645,
        "Profit": -144
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-05-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 2578,
        "Profit": 692
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-06-30T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 3160,
        "Profit": 897
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-07-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 1211,
        "Profit": 197
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-08-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 7105,
        "Profit": 1621
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-09-30T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 3088,
        "Profit": 427
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-10-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 3336,
        "Profit": 755
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-11-30T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 6746,
        "Profit": 1021
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-12-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 6517,
        "Profit": 690
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Art",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-01-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 434,
        "Profit": 111
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Art",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-02-29T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 247,
        "Profit": 67
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Art",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-03-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 442,
        "Profit": 115
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Art",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-04-30T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 618,
        "Profit": 140
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Art",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-05-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 640,
        "Profit": 177
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Art",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-06-30T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 1019,
        "Profit": 262
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Art",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-07-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 867,
        "Profit": 251
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Art",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-08-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 733,
        "Profit": 199
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Art",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-09-30T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 971,
        "Profit": 267
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Art",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-10-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 642,
        "Profit": 123
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Art",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-11-30T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 1387,
        "Profit": 312
      },
      {
        "Sub-Category": "Art",
        "MonthendDate": "2020-12-31T00:00:00",
        "Sales": 862,
        "Profit": 199
      }   
    ]
  },
  "spacing": {"row": 2},
  "facet": {
    "row": {
      "field": "Sub-Category",
      "type": "nominal",
        "header": {
        "title": null,
        "labelAngle": 0,
        "labelPadding": 0,
        "titlePadding": -40,
        "labelAlign": "left"
      }
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "width": 120,
    "height": 20,
    "view": {"stroke": "transparent"},
        "mark": {"type": "area", "interpolate": "natural"},
        "encoding": {
          "x": {
            "field": "MonthendDate",
            "type": "temporal",
            "title": null,
            "timeUnit": "yearmonth",
            "axis": {"format": "%b %y", "orient": "top",
            }
          },
          "y": {
            "field": "Sales",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "aggregate": "sum",
            "scale": {"zero": true},
            "axis": {"title": null, "labels": false, "ticks": false}
          }
        }
      },
  "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "shared"}}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is currently a bug which you can read more about here: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5547. If you edit the Vega spec instead, you can achieve what you want.

[Final Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYfzi.png)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "background": "white",
  "padding": 5,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "source_0",
      "values": [
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-01-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 2126,
          "Profit": 476
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-02-29T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 2437,
          "Profit": 623
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-03-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 3952,
          "Profit": 1192
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-04-30T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 2142,
          "Profit": 358
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-05-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 3751,
          "Profit": 1190
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-06-30T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 4849,
          "Profit": 1028
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-07-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 7589,
          "Profit": 2403
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-08-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 4962,
          "Profit": 1154
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-09-30T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 9727,
          "Profit": 2778
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-10-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 5032,
          "Profit": 909
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-11-30T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 8390,
          "Profit": 2181
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Accessories",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-12-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 4989,
          "Profit": 1380
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-01-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 2548,
          "Profit": 423
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-02-29T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 3521,
          "Profit": 977
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-03-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 2474,
          "Profit": 308
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-04-30T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 645,
          "Profit": -144
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-05-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 2578,
          "Profit": 692
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-06-30T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 3160,
          "Profit": 897
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-07-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 1211,
          "Profit": 197
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-08-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 7105,
          "Profit": 1621
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-09-30T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 3088,
          "Profit": 427
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-10-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 3336,
          "Profit": 755
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-11-30T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 6746,
          "Profit": 1021
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Appliances",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-12-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 6517,
          "Profit": 690
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Art",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-01-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 434,
          "Profit": 111
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Art",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-02-29T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 247,
          "Profit": 67
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Art",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-03-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 442,
          "Profit": 115
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Art",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-04-30T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 618,
          "Profit": 140
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Art",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-05-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 640,
          "Profit": 177
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Art",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-06-30T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 1019,
          "Profit": 262
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Art",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-07-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 867,
          "Profit": 251
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Art",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-08-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 733,
          "Profit": 199
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Art",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-09-30T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 971,
          "Profit": 267
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Art",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-10-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 642,
          "Profit": 123
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Art",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-11-30T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 1387,
          "Profit": 312
        },
        {
          "Sub-Category": "Art",
          "MonthendDate": "2020-12-31T00:00:00",
          "Sales": 862,
          "Profit": 199
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_0",
      "source": "source_0",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "toDate(datum[\"MonthendDate\"])",
          "as": "MonthendDate"
        },
        {
          "field": "MonthendDate",
          "type": "timeunit",
          "units": ["year", "month"],
          "as": ["yearmonth_MonthendDate", "yearmonth_MonthendDate_end"]
        },
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["yearmonth_MonthendDate", "Sub-Category"],
          "ops": ["sum"],
          "fields": ["Sales"],
          "as": ["sum_Sales"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "row_domain",
      "source": "data_0",
      "transform": [{"type": "aggregate", "groupby": ["Sub-Category"]}]
    }
  ],
  "signals": [
    {"name": "child_width", "value": 120},
    {"name": "child_height", "value": 20}
  ],
  "layout": {
    "padding": {"row": 2, "column": 20},
    "columns": 1,
    "bounds": "full",
    "align": "all"
  },
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "row_header",
      "type": "group",
      "role": "row-header",
      "from": {"data": "row_domain"},
      "sort": {"field": "datum[\"Sub-Category\"]", "order": "ascending"},
      "title": {
        "text": {
          "signal": "isValid(parent[\"Sub-Category\"]) ? parent[\"Sub-Category\"] : \"\"+parent[\"Sub-Category\"]"
        },
        "orient": "right",
        "style": "guide-label",
        "frame": "group",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "align": "right",
        "angle": 0,
        "offset": -60
      },
      "encode": {"update": {"height": {"signal": "child_height"}}},
      "axes": [
        {
          "scale": "y",
          "orient": "left",
          "grid": false,
          "labels": false,
          "ticks": false,
          "labelOverlap": true,
          "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(child_height/40)"},
          "zindex": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "column_header",
      "type": "group",
      "role": "column-header",
      "encode": {"update": {"width": {"signal": "child_width"}}},
      "axes": [
        {
          "scale": "x",
          "orient": "top",
          "grid": false,
          "format": "%b %y",
          "labelFlush": true,
          "labelOverlap": true,
          "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(child_width/40)"},
          "zindex": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "cell",
      "type": "group",
      "style": "cell",
      "from": {
        "facet": {
          "name": "facet",
          "data": "data_0",
          "groupby": ["Sub-Category"]
        }
      },
      "sort": {"field": ["datum[\"Sub-Category\"]"], "order": ["ascending"]},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "width": {"signal": "child_width"},
          "height": {"signal": "child_height"},
          "stroke": {"value": "transparent"}
        }
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "name": "child_marks",
          "type": "area",
          "style": ["area"],
          "sort": {"field": "datum[\"yearmonth_MonthendDate\"]"},
          "from": {"data": "facet"},
          "encode": {
            "update": {
              "interpolate": {"value": "natural"},
              "orient": {"value": "vertical"},
              "fill": {"value": "#4c78a8"},
              "description": {
                "signal": "\"MonthendDate (year-month): \" + (timeFormat(datum[\"yearmonth_MonthendDate\"], '%b %y')) + \"; Sum of Sales: \" + (format(datum[\"sum_Sales\"], \"\"))"
              },
              "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "yearmonth_MonthendDate"},
              "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "sum_Sales"},
              "y2": {"scale": "y", "value": 0},
              "defined": {
                "signal": "isValid(datum[\"yearmonth_MonthendDate\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"yearmonth_MonthendDate\"]) && isValid(datum[\"sum_Sales\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"sum_Sales\"])"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "axes": [
        {
          "scale": "x",
          "orient": "top",
          "gridScale": "y",
          "grid": true,
          "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(child_width/40)"},
          "domain": false,
          "labels": false,
          "aria": false,
          "maxExtent": 0,
          "minExtent": 0,
          "ticks": false,
          "zindex": 0
        },
        {
          "scale": "y",
          "orient": "left",
          "gridScale": "x",
          "grid": true,
          "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(child_height/40)"},
          "domain": false,
          "labels": false,
          "aria": false,
          "maxExtent": 0,
          "minExtent": 0,
          "ticks": false,
          "zindex": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "time",
      "domain": {"data": "data_0", "field": "yearmonth_MonthendDate"},
      "range": [0, {"signal": "child_width"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {"data": "data_0", "field": "sum_Sales"},
      "range": [{"signal": "child_height"}, 0],
      "zero": true,
      "nice": true
    }
  ],
  "config": {"style": {"cell": {"stroke": "transparent"}}}
}
```

Comment: Congrats on hitting #2 for [powerbi]

Comment: Thanks horseyride. My dreams of number 1 are likely over though as the site has completely dried up. Did you see this? https://old.reddit.com/r/ChatGPT/comments/15ju114/chatgpt_is_putting_stack_overflow_out_of_business/

Comment: I'm sure you'll make it. So few people upvote their answers though. I'll remember to upvote more of yours when I see them.

Comment: Lol. We'll see. They all deserved votes so they are justified.

Comment: Ha - I see those posts and think "no thank you". There are just so many low effort posts, you can already tell who will engage and show the minimum amount of gratitude.